# Why is resonse from Facebook Graph /promotable_posts edge empty after API v2.9

Tags: facebook-graph-api

```
GET v2.8 <PAGEID>/promotable_posts?include_inline=true&include_hidden=true&fields=created_time,id,message
```

(with a Page Access token) returns a list of all posts on the page, including "dark posts".

However, from v2.9 onwards, the same API call returns an empty list.

The [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/page/feed) don't seem to mention anything beyond needing to use either a Page Access token, or a User access token with ads_management permission. I'm using the same app, with the same permissions, in all cases. The app has the following permissions: user_posts, email, read_insights, manage_pages, pages_show_list, ads_management, ads_read, business_management, public_profile.

The 2.9 [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.9) doesn't seem to say anything relevant, as far as I can tell.

Does anyone know what step I am missing to view the list of promotable_posts in v2.9 or later?

Answer (score 0):

Empirically it seems that the person authorising the app needs to have a role on the Page that permits them to create ads. This shows up in the "perms" field of the Page node (returned from the /accounts edge) as CREATE_ADS.

A role of (for example) Page Analyst gives only the permission BASIC_ADMIN which, post-v2.9, doesn't seem to be good enough.

I've still not found any documentation on this, so would welcome any further information (or a workaround!)

EDIT: This answer is out of date. Since Facebook's deprecation of Page roles, the whole permission system has changed and there is no longer a "perms" field.